# android contacts sync with google+ facebook

Tags: contacts, facebook, google-contacts

I'm using Pixel (XL), Phone by Google (1st generation) with Android 8.0.0, when I tap on `Contacts` app, some of my contains has photo and some do not(.

How does one sync my existing contacts against Google+ and/or Facebook to get photos? I don't want to sync entire Facebook against my phone...

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

first of all do these things ..

- Run App permission management in your phone .(Some device has its own inbuilt app , or lots of apps available on play store.)
- You can go to your setting  > security > permission > deny all contact permission
- go to setting > Account > Google > Your Account > untick contact no sync with google.